# How to call ILOG JRules business Rules using Java?

Tags: java, ilog

I have made the business Rules using ILOG Studio and deployed the business rule to RES. Now I want to use that business rule in java project.

What are the ways to call/consume the business rules using Java and which libraries I need to import in java project? Kindly provide some link or sample for calling business rules.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of ways to consume using Java.
The simplest and the recommended ways are ...

1. Invoking the Rule in a J2EE environment using IlrPOJOSessionFactory. All the details and code sample are provided in this [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/brjrules/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ilog.jrules.doc/html/api/html/ilog/rules/res/session/IlrPOJOSessionFactory.html).
2. Invoking the Rule in a J2SE environment using IlrJ2SESessionFactory . All the details and code sample are provided in this [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/brjrules/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ilog.jrules.doc/html/api/html/ilog/rules/res/session/IlrJ2SESessionFactory.html).

The Jar files you need to import are as follows.

1. jrules-engine.jar
2. jrules-res-XXXX-session-java.jar   (XXXX - represent the version of the ILOG you are using)
3. jrules-res-execution.jar
4. jrules-res-session-XXXX.jar (XXXX - Represents the app server you are using websphere/weblogic etc..)

Spring framework also provide a JSR 94 template to invoke business rules deployed in RES from J2SE and J2EE component.

Comment: Any new links? they are broken now